# How to load Fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am new to kotlin I am adding bottom bar in my app

```
val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<View>(R.id.navigation) as BottomNavigationView
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView)
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        var selectedFragment: Fragment? = null
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_item1 -> selectedFragment = ItemOneFragment.newInstance()
            R.id.action_item2 -> selectedFragment = ItemTwoFragment.newInstance()
            R.id.action_item3 -> selectedFragment = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance()
            R.id.action_item4 -> selectedFragment = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance()
        }
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment)
        transaction.commit()
        true
    }

    //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, ItemOneFragment.newInstance())
    transaction.commit()
```

ItemOneFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 public class ItemOneFragment extends Fragment {
 public static ItemOneFragment newInstance() {
    ItemOneFragment fragment = new ItemOneFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_one, container, false);
}}
```

But I am getting the error :
type mismatch Required : Fragment at ItemOneFragment.newInstance()
I have tried all stuff 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the method `ItemOneFragment.newInstance()`?

Comment: Christian Brüggemann
I have made fragment

Comment: Yes, but can you post the code of that method (and maybe even the whole class) here?

Comment: I have posted all code @ChristianBrüggemann

Comment: Where are you assigning `supportFragmentManager ` variable? Check it again and make sure you are calling `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're importing `android.app.Fragment` in the file containing your `bottomNavigationView` code. `ItemOneFragment.newInstance()` returns `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, which would be incompatible with `android.app.Fragment`.

Changing the import to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` should solve the issue.